# CSS Organization Structure Chart

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML & CSS Organization Structure Chart and I think this is a simple question.
Here is the demo in **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tgCu/)**

css

```
    /*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree

{
width: auto;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.tree ul {
padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
float: left; text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 50%; height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after{
right: auto; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after{
border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before{
content: '';
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 0; height: 20px;
}


.tree li a{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #666;
font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
display: inline-block;

border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;

transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}

/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

What I want to do is : How to make just line before IT Support - David Alwis. Because We see the position is same like IT - Support Juanda.

Anyone please help!

Updated answer by Itay in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/4tgCu/5/)

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to do. Consider creating a picture of the wanted result.

Comment: Please see the demo in JS fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/4tgCu/

Comment: You see there is 1 empty box before David Alwis ? That's exactly my question, how to make it just line ? not a empty box

Comment: and that's the actual structure you want? shouldn't the "Assistant Engineers" be siblings?

Comment: Simple question: how to make the empty box to be line ? because there is no Engineer above David Alwis.

Comment: The original CSS seems to come from http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/4tgCu/5/)

Added these styles:

```
.tree ul ul::before{
    margin-left: -1px;
}
li a.just-line {
    display: none;
}
a.just-line + ul {
    padding-top: 74px;
}
a.just-line + ul:before {
    height: 74px;
}
```

Comment: It's not aligned in Chrome. The vertical line where the box used to be is offset to the right.

Comment: I saw, but it's not neatly

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I meant Firefox. Firefox 23 to be exact. (Clearly it's been a long day....)

Comment: @Itay in my Firefox 23.0.1, the line is not straight.

Comment: @NoReply If you look at the fullscreen version of Itay's fix, it looks straight in Firefox 23: http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/4tgCu/4/embedded/result/ . I think maybe JSFiddle's split-screen layout might be throwing something off.

Comment: OK got it. Now how to remove the line hover ? without disturb another hover ?

Comment: Yeah. thats excatly what I wanted @Itay. Thank you... :)

Answer (score 2):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4tgCu/1/

```
.tree li.connect-left > a:before,
.tree li.connect-right > a:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -11px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 11px;
}

.tree li.connect-left > a:before {
    left: -11px;
    right: auto;
}
```

Added an additional class that you can use to connect adjacent ones to the next.

Comment: That's really nice but it's not what the OP was after :)

Comment: Ah, derp. Didn't understand what he meant until you posted your version.